# Dynamic rendering - unable to find component with clientId

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am rendering a xhtml to a dialog whose components are added dynamically from server side using [Dynamic example](http://www.softwareengineeringsolutions.com/thoughts/frameworks/JSF.Techniques-Adding.Components.Dynamically.htm).

Using PrimeFaces 5.1, JSF 2.1 Mojarra and tomcat 7.

When i click the close button of the pop up a large number to of unable to find the component is being seen the eclipse console due to which the close action is having slow response.

Tried changing the *prependId* to *true* on the *myForm*. Also tried *replacing* the *@form* from *update* attribute of the close button with *:myForm*.
Both the methods was not successful.

I would like to know how to prevent this *unable to find component* being triggered.

> Unable to find component with clientId editOwnerForm:tab:j_id16:iq_16_panelGroup2', no need to remove it.
>
> Unable to find component with clientId
>   'editOwnerForm:tab:j_id16:j_id235', no need to remove it. 
>   Unable to
>   find component with clientId 'editOwnerForm:tab:j_id16:j_id236', no
>   need to remove it. 
>   Unable to find component with clientId
>   'editOwnerForm:tab:j_id16:j_id237', no need to remove it. 
>   Unable to
>   find component with clientId 'editOwnerForm:tab:j_id16:j_id238', no
>   need to remove it. 
>   Unable to find component with clientId
>   'editOwnerForm:tab:j_id16:j_id239', no need to remove it. 
>   Unable to
>   find component with clientId 'editOwnerForm:tab:j_id16:j_id240', no
>   need to remove it. 
>   Unable to find component with clientId
>   'editOwnerForm:tab:j_id16:j_id241', no need to remove it. 
>   Unable to
>   find component with clientId 'editOwnerForm:tab:j_id16:j_id242', no
>   need to remove it. 
>   Unable to find component with clientId
>   'editOwnerForm:tab:j_id16:j_id243', no need to remove it. 
>   Unable to find component with clientId editOwnerForm:tab:j_id16:iq_17_225', no need to remove it. 
>   Unable to find component with clientId
>   'editOwnerForm:tab:j_id16:iq_17_panelGroup2', no need to remove it.

myForm.xhtml

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="form">
    <p:commandButton id="editOwnerButtonId" oncomplete="PF('editOwnerDlgVar').show();"
    actionListener="#{myViewBean.editOwner}"
    update=":editOwnerForm" icon="ui-icon-pencil"
    iconPos="right">
    <f:param name="ownerId"
            value="#{myViewBean.id}" />
     </p:commandButton>
</h:form>

<p:dialog id="editOwnerDlgId" widgetVar="editOwnerDlgVar"
    modal="true" closable="true" width="1200px" height="600" >
    <ui:include src="ownerEdit.xhtml" />
</p:dialog>
```

ownerEdit.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
    lang="en" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:shiro="http://shiro.apache.org/tags">

     <h:form prependId="true" id="editOwnerForm">
        <p:tabView id="tab" style="border-width:0px;"
        activeIndex="#{myViewBean.tanIndex}">
               <p:tab >

               </p:tab >
           <p:tab id="dynamicResponse" title="Dynamic Response">
            <h:panelGroup id="sections"
                binding="#{myViewBean.panelGroup}">
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>

    <p:commandButton value="Close" update=":form" id="cancelButton"
        immediate="true"
        actionListener="#{myViewBean.cancelOwner}"
        icon="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-w" iconPos="right">
        <p:ajax listener="#{myViewBean.setTabIndex}" />
    </p:commandButton>
  </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

MyViewBean Dynamic Rendering code - triggered on click edit button

```
HtmlPanelGroup panelGroup = new HtmlPanelGroup();
panelGroup.getChildren().clear();
TabView tabView = new TabView();
Tab sectionTab = (Tab) tabView.findComponent("sec_" + question.getSectionId());
sectionTab.setId("sec_" + question.getSectionId());
sectionTab.setTitle(question.getSectionName());

HtmlPanelGrid pg = new HtmlPanelGrid();
pg.setColumns(3);

OutputLabel questionText = new OutputLabel();
questionText.setValue(question.getTitle());
pg.getChildren().add(questionText);

OutputLabel coln1 = new OutputLabel();
coln1.setValue(":");
pg.getChildren().add(coln1);

final String respBind = "#{myViewBean.questionResponse[\""+ question.getId()+ "_"+ pet.getId()+ "_"+ question.getMultiPet() + "\"]}";
final ValueExpression resp = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()
                                .getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), respBind,   String.class);
InputText value = new InputText();
value.setId("iq_"+ String.valueOf(question.getId()) + "_"+ String.valueOf(pet.getId()));
value.setSize(20);
value.setValueExpression("value", resp);

pg.getChildren().add(value);

sectionTab.getChildren().clear();
sectionTab.getChildren().add(pg);
tabView.getChildren().add(sectionTab);
panelGroup.getChildren().add(tabView);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got solution to this issue...To fix "Unable to find component with clientId 'tab:j_id16:sec_4', no need to remove it.", the we have to update the jsf jars to from 2.1.7 to 2.1.9 or to 2.1.29.
In the below links, this is reported as an issue of Mojarra.

See the links 
    http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22880
    https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2383
    https://java.net/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10204&version=15535